# Infinite map in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, racing

I'm working on my first project on Unity 3D, I'm making an endless racing 3D. I took a highway asset from the Unity Store. The road isn't straight, it has many curves and is very long. I would ask you: how do I make the road endless?

Comment: Do you mean repeat the same road endlessly?

Comment: @Siddharth yess

Comment: Then you can create duplicate of Gameobject in c# script. Please refer the unity manual.@bova1973

Answer (score 0):

You can create a few patterns, and all of this patterns can start and end with straight road, so you can design however u want between this two straight road :)
after you create 5-10 patterns like this after that you can instantiate this patterns behind and behind so i think this will work four you :)

Comment: you mean i have to add a lot of patterns in a row and then I copy and paste them?

Comment: actually no need to "a loth" just create 10 different pattern and after that you can randomly spawn that patterns with instantiate, just an idea :) i dont know any "easy" solution for this, or you can create an algorithm like "if you spawn x object and after that u create y object than change y objects position and rotation for this" this will be little bit more long and complex but it can be work or just use my first advice :D no one can understand same patterns in game because peoples will focus the game :D i hope i can help ^^